# NativeScript angular nativeView undefined

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to get `StackLayout` nativeView from NativeScript Angular but always returning `undefined`. I tried like this:

html:

```
<StackLayout id="stackLayout" #stackLayout> </StackLayout>
```

TS:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let container: StackLayout = this.page.getViewById("stackLayout");
        console.log(container.nativeView); 
        console.log(this.stackLayout.nativeElement.nativeView);
    }, 100)
}
```

Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `loaded` event of the View itself which ensures the `nativeView` is ready.

**HTML**

```
<StackLayout (loaded)="onLoaded($event)"></StackLayout>
```

**TS**

```
onLoaded(event: EventData) {
  const stackLayout = <StackLayout>event.object;
  console.log(stackLayout.nativeView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems to work but I am trying to attach `android.webkit.WebView` to that view. I am trying like this: `stackLayout.nativeView.addView(this.agent.getWebCreator().getWebView())` but getting error: `JS: ERROR Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
`. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your purpose, but if you are trying to inject a native view, you should use a `Placeholder`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! `Placeholder` has solved my problem :)